# How to use drop down list's value from a HTML page into a servlet?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to create a simple calculator using servlets and HTML. For 1 operation it works, but how do I use a structure like

```
if (+) {
    k=i+j;
} else if (-) {
    k=i-j;
}
```

I mean to say, what should I write in the `if` condition to get the drop down list's value?

My drop down list is like below:

```html
<select name="select1">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
</select>
```

I'm using Tomcat 6 on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Just get it as request parameter the usual way, like as you did for all other HTML input elements.

```
String operator = request.getParameter("select1");
```

*(I'd for clarity only rename the `<select name="select1">` to `<select name="operator">`)*

Then, to compare the string values, use the [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method (and thus **not** `==`!):

```
if ("+".equals(operator)) {
    // ...
} else if ("-".equals(operator)) {
    // ...
} else if ("*".equals(operator)) {
    // ...
} else if ("/".equals(operator)) {
    // ...
}
```

You might want to consider looking into enums or upgrading to Java 7 (so that you can use a `switch` which supports since Java 7 also strings), so that you don't end up with an ugly nested if-else block. To get a step further, checkout the command pattern. But I assume that this is homework, so nevermind ;)

Comment: @NasrinhakimMithila: You should accept the answer if it works for you